# Can't compile a Swift package which is using an Objective-C package

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, package

I am trying to capsule native C++ code with an Objective-C module. This works fine.
Next I am trying to use that module from Swift, but I am not able to use the Objective-C class from Swift code. I have tried build two separate modules or one module with two targets - same error "**Use of unresolved identifier 'Bridge'**" and also a warning, that the **umbrella directory** ../Objective-CCode/include is not found.

I guess that the bridging header between Objective-C and Swift is missing. In a mixed code environment this header is generated automatically, but not in the package management.

*What is missing or what is my fault?* I have attached a small example of my problem.

> "Package.swift" Package description.

```
// swift-tools-version:5.1

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MixedExample",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MixedExample",
            targets: ["SwiftCode", "Objective-CCode"]),
],
dependencies: [

],
targets: [
    .target(name: "SwiftCode", dependencies: ["Objective-CCode"]),
    .target(name: "Objective-CCode", dependencies: []),    
    ]
)
```

> Module "Objective-CCode" with Objektive-C code:
>   "Bridge.h"

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Bridge : NSObject

-(void) printHello;

@end
```

> "Bridge.m"

```
#include "Bridge.h"

@implementation Bridge : NSObject

-(void)printHello {
    fprintf(stdout, "Hello from ExampleBridge\n");
}

@end
```

> Module "SwiftCode" with Swift code

```
import Foundation
import Objective_CCode

class Examples {

    let e = Bridge()   // compiler error here

    func printH() {
        e.printHello()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I have searched for **umbrella directory**, which brought me to the solution.

This article https://medium.com/allatoneplace/challenges-building-a-swift-framework-d882867c97f9 explains the usage of the umbrella directory, which is needed to call the C* classes from swift.

For the above example the solution would be

> Add an include directory to the Objective-C package with the following file "MixedExample.h"

```
#include "../Bridge.h"
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand your solution here. could you please provide an example?

Comment: @NateMann
The example is complete. It is important that files and directories have the correct names. So if the package is called "MixedExample", you need a header file, called "MixedExample.h" in your Objective-CCode include path. This file should include the header file of your code. (In my example, Bridge.h)

Comment: It worked for me, but I needed to clean the project before.

Comment: Post deleted. :(